# app's shortcut icon not updated after upgrading the app in samsung galaxy S3

Tags: android, android-4.2-jelly-bean, samsung-mobile

I recently updated my app's icon picture. But the shortcut icon in Samsung Galaxy S3 phones are not updated accordingly. Other models work fine with updated icons.

Here is how I updated the icon in my project (kinda trivial):
- Replaced the old ic_launcher.png in all drawable-* directories with new pictures;
- Ran the app through IDE;

the codes in the project is also trivial:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" > ... </application>
```

It looks like a model-specific bug for Samsung Galaxy S3.
The spec for this phone:
Model: SPH-L710.
Android Version: 4.1.2(API 16).
Carrier: Sprint.

My question is:
Is there anyway to update the shortcut icon in this specific model? If no, is there any way to remove that icon with the old icon grammatically?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: "Is there anyway to update the shortcut icon in this specific model?" -- reboot the device.

Comment: Yeah, there's no requirement that a home screen automatically reflect updates to icons and labels. They *should*, but they are not required to.

Comment: @CommonsWare All Google images reflect updates. This Samsung model is weird ...

Comment: Why after restart the problem is solved? is this a known Android issue?